# How do I get the first word that starts with a number using regex and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out how to write a regex pattern that catches all words which begins after the first number. Two examples below for clarity:

```
var string1 = "Area 51"; // This is the string I have
var match1 = "51"; // This is the string I want
```

or this:

```
var string2 = "A simple sentence with 6 words or more" // This is the string I have
var matchedString = "6 words or more" // This is the string I want
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  regex **[`\b\d+\b.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gH7sE4/4)** and method **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** for pattern match

```js
var string1 = "Area 51"; // This is the string I have
var match1 = string1.match(/\b\d+\b.*$/)[0];

var string2 = "A simple sentence with 6 words or more" // This is the string I have
var matchedString = string2.match(/\b\d+\b.*$/)[0]; // This is the string I want

document.write(match1+'<br>'+matchedString);
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gH7sE4/4)**

```
\b\d+\b.*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/D7WDyWByqR2p5PtT)

Comment: This will fail when there is a number in the middle of a word. `"A simpl1e sentence with 6 words or more"` will return `1e sentence with 6 words or more` for example. Use a word boundary like `match(/\b\d.*/)[0]`

Comment: Seems okay after the edit, but it will now only match words that are just numbers. For example it will not match `1string`. The question is not clear on this, so this may or may not be the wanted behaviour.

Comment: @Ozan : thanks for your kind of support , updated again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `\b` word boundary followed by `\d` to find a word starting with a number.

```js
var str = "Simple test1 String 2where there rand3om number4s through5out.";
alert(str.match(/\b\d.*/)[0]);
```